# PHP with Bootstrap Carousel not working once dynamic

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I am using Kirby cms and creating a dynamic bootstrap 4 carousel. All elements display so all the images in the database along with the correct number of indicators. The issue is the carosuel does not work anymore, all images are layered on top of each other and the indicators do not work anymore. Have I added a close div tag in the wrong place or something?

```
<div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide carousel-fade col-md-12" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php $n=0; foreach($page->images() as $image): ?>
            <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="<?php echo $n; $n++; ?>" class="<?php if($n==1) echo ' active' ?>">
                <?php echo $n; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?> 
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php $n=0; foreach($page->images() as $image): $n++; ?>
            <div class="item<?php if($n==1) echo ' active' ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $image->url() ?>" alt="<?php echo html($image->title()) ?>" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does the generated HTML looks inside navigator (Chrome+F12)?

Answer (score 0):

When I reverted back to bootstrap 3 it worked like a charm.